# Ways to implement Janrain Engage (RPXNow) on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, session, rpxnow, janrain

What a some possible solutions to best implement Janrain Engage (RPX Now) on Google App Engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a complete solution including sessions, I recommend [gae-sessions](http://github.com/dound/gae-sessions/wiki).  The source includes a [demo](http://github.com/dound/gae-sessions/tree/master//demo/) which shows how to integrate the sessions library with [Janrain/RPX](http://www.janrain.com/).

Disclaimer: I wrote gae-sessions, but for an informative comparison of it with alternatives, read [this article](http://github.com/dound/gae-sessions/wiki/comparison-with-alternative-libraries).

Answer (score 0):

According to this [HOWTO](http://groups.google.com/group/rpx-developers/web/rpx-on-google-app-engine?pli=1), it seems to be pretty trivial.

Comment: Yes, but you need to tie that into a session system. I'm interested in finding more complete solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This may [article](http://developers.janrain.com/articles/google-appengine) help you and you can combine this with the [webapp2](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html) which I believe already supports sessions.